# Analog to digital conversion for neural network weights

Tags: digital-logic, resistors, analog

I am a machine learning researcher, and lately I am getting interested in neural networks trained on analog hardware. However, I have some doubts about their potential, probably because I am missing key details. For example, I know that, in an analog hardware, each weight is a programmable resistor, whose conductance represents a parameter to be adjusted during training. Let us assume we manage to train a neural network on an analog chip, and that we have the learned weights (= conductance of resistors): now, we should be able to use the chip to perform inference (right?).

Let us now assume that we want to perform inference using the same network on a digital hardware, due to its flexibility. Is it possible to transfer the trained weights from analog to digital? So, in other words, is it possible to copy the trained neural network on the analog chip, and "paste" it on a digital one?

Comment: If the "programmable resistors" are digitally-controlled analog devices, then the same digital controls should be transferrable by some means to a fully digital system.

Comment: Are analog chips normally digitally-controlled analog devices? Or is it a special kind of hardware not really used in practice?

Comment: It would depend on the specific chip. If it's designed to be able to extract the weights, then it can. If it's not designed to, maybe it still can, or maybe it can't. This is the cutting edge of technology we're talking about - it's not standardized in any way.

Comment: Ok, do you have any reference? What are the drawbacks of designing a chip able to extract the weights? Thank you!! :)